# conversion of infix to postfix with 3 classes (no buffer reader)

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using netbeans and I'm still a beginner at this things.
In main class we should input an expression which should be a string and it also should display the converted postfix.
Then the 3 classes, class Stack, class checkExpression and class Convert. 
I don't know what to put in those 3 classes. Please help me. Thanks :)

Comment: How would you attempt to solve it and where are you stuck?

Comment: Actually, I know what to do in main. But in the classes. I don't know if I will combine all those 3 in one class.

Comment: Yeah. Actually this is a project that is a 50% of our final grade. And she didn't discussed thoroughly about classes.

Comment: Do operators have different priorities or is everything left-associative?

Comment: I really don't know. She discusses just the algorithm of stacks and give that project. Sorry, can't give a definite answers.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are good for seperating different, reusable components, so you should have one such component per class. I would do it this way:

- `Stack` is a class that represents a parser stack. It has methods for pushing symbols on the stack and for retrieving them.
- `Convert` is a class that uses the `Stack` class for converting a string. It contains a method that, in a big loop, does the following things (some of them in seperate methods):

  - fetch a token from the input string
  - append the token to the stack (using a method provided by the `Stack` class)
  - while the second-last token is an operator (or the third-last and the last token are `(` and `)`), replace the last three tokens with a postfix-form string (e.g. replace `[..., "1", "+", "2"] with [..., "1 2 +"])

  Afterwards, return the Stack.
  Also, `Convert` would contain your `main` method that reads a string, converts it, checks the result using `CheckExpression` and then prints the result or an error message.
- I would make `CheckExpression` a class that contains a method that checks whether a string was converted completely by checking whether the resulting stack has just one element (the result).

This assumes a purely left-associative grammar, so for example, `3 + 4 * 5` would be parsed as `(3 + 4) * 5` (however, `3 + (4 * 5)` would also be parsed as `3 + (4 * 5)`).

Maybe you should ask your teacher whether implementing it as a purely left-associative parser is ok and whether that way of structuring the classes is good? 50% of your final grade is a lot, so you should really be able to get something more specific from him/her.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll be discussing this to her. :)